# Neovim diffrent behaviour than vim on spelling sugestion

Tags: neovim, insert-mode, spell-checking, spelling

First thing first I am writing a foreign language with a different keyboard(greek-english).
I was trying some spell checking features of vim and neovim and I noticed that neovim might have a bug.

At the beginning I tried vim and everything worked fine, then I tried neovim and it didn't.Steps to reproduce:

1. I let neovim download and install a `spellfile` on my pc with`:set spelllang=el`
2. Typed `z=` over a wrong word(everything worked fine)
3. Then I got on insert mode and pressed `ctrl-x s` (with English on keyboard and cursor at the end of the word)

and an error appeared `-- Spelling suggestion (s^N^P) Pattern not found` .

I did both experiments without plugins or special configurations (`neovim -u NONE`) but I couldn't do it with `neovim --clean`   because then it couldn't locate the spell files.

PS:If you don't have a Greek keyboard and you want to reproduce but you are lazy to find Greek words you can try the word `Αλάνι` which is correct and try to remove the last character.

Comment: That's my version by the way NVIM v0.7.0-dev+683-gafaad8b54

Comment: I would report this to the neovim devs

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah I will do it also but I just want to be sure that it is not something idiotic on my side, and I am doing everything correct.Maybe I will try it on a cleaner pc than mine, I have very dirty folders on $home/.local/shar/nvim/site/spell